# Calling a shell script from a C++ program with parameters

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, system

I am trying a call a shell script from a cpp program and passing some variables to the script. The script simply copies a file from one directory to another. I want to pass the name of the file, the source directory and the destination directory to shell script from the cpp program. I get the error omitting directory "/" when I try. Please how can I fix this

C++ Code:

```cxx
std::string spath="/home/henry/work/gcu/build/lib/hardware_common/";

std::string dpath="/home/henry/work/gcu/dll/";

std::string filename="libhardware_common.a";

std::system("/home/henry/work/gcu/build/binaries/bin/copy.sh spath dpath filename");
```

Shell Script code:

```sh
SPATH=${spath}

DPATH=${dpath}

FILE=${filename}

cp ${SPATH}/${FILE} ${DPATH}/${FILE}
```

Comment: `spath` and `dpath` and not substituted in your C++ code. They will be the literals `spath` and `dpath`. Maybe you should use a `std::ostringstream` and insert them into a command to use with `std::system`. You should probably show more of your shell code, too. I think there are some things wrong with it but more contrext is probably needed.

Comment: `[teach-me]` You have some misconceptions about strings and variable names in C and in shell. `"dpath" ` string in C does not magically become `"/home/henry/work/gcu/dll/"` when you pass it to `system()`. Nor can shell access command line arguments by their C variable names - look into `$1`,  `$2`and so on in shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++ code and the shell script are **not** in the same scope. In other words, variables in C++ will not be visible in your script, and when passed to the script, the variables will be renamed as `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

To fix it, you can change your code to the following:

```
std::string spath = "/home/henry/work/gcu/build/lib/hardware_common/";

std::string dpath = "/home/henry/work/gcu/dll/";

std::string filename = "libhardware_common.a";

std::string shell = "/home/henry/work/gcu/build/binaries/bin/copy.sh"

std::system(shell + " " + spath + " " + dpath + " " + filename);
```

In this way, the `spath` will be substituted by the value of it, which is then passed to your script.

In your script, you can use:

```
cp $1/$2 $3/$2
```

or if you prefer:

```
SPATH=$1

DPATH=$2

FILE=$3

cp ${SPATH}/${FILE} ${DPATH}/${FILE}
```

The script will never know the variable name in the C++ code. When the script is called, the parameters will be replaced by `$1`, `$2`...

Comment: Just a caveat: if any of the `spath`, `dpath` and `filename` have any spaces in them, the code in the answer will break. More elaborate approach would be needed then.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Or asterisk, or dollar sign, or backticks... It is worth noting that this sort of thing is pretty rare in production code, because it is a likely source of security holes. (At the very least, whoever is reviewing your code will need to spend some time proving that it's not.)